# Css header with three divs side by side responsive

Tags: html, css

I have created this simple header and was wondering if this is a good way to put divs side by side? 
Also am I centering divs correctly or should I use pixels for width instead of percents?

Live demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/d4v91ekb/

```css
a {
   text-decoration:none;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1200px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row {
    overflow:hidden;
}
.header {
    padding: 8px 8px 32px 8px;
    background: #FFCA00;
    height: 200px;
}
.logo {
    background: url('https://placehold.it/200x200') no-repeat;
    background-size: 100px 100px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    text-indent:-100%;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
}
.siteName {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top: 40px;
    font-size: 15pt;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    float:left;
}

.mainNav {
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    width:50%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
.mainNav ul{
        list-style-type: none;
        text-align: center;
    }
.mainNav ul li{
        display:inline;
    }
.mainNav ul li a{
        color:#fff;
        padding: 5px;
    }
.mainNav ul li a:hover{
        padding: 5px;
        border-bottom:2px solid #fff;
    }
.mainNav .current{
        padding: 5px;
        color:black;
        border-bottom:2px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="header" class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row"> 
            
                <a href="index.html" title=""><div class="logo"></div></a>
                <a href="index.html" title=""><div class="siteName">Site full name here</div></a>
                
            <nav class="mainNav">
                <ul>
                    <li class="current"><a href="" title="">Menu 01</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" title="">Menu 02</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" title="">Menu 03</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" title="">Menu 04</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            
            </div>
        </div>
    </header><!-- /header -->
```

Comment: What is your mean to asking? Please clarify what do you want?

Comment: @SantoshKhalse on my computer the menu is not centering and is right by the site full name instead center. So I was wondering if this is just for my computer or there is some error in code why its not in the middle.

Comment: I'm not sure if SO is the best place to get code reviews. Maybe the [Code-Review-Community](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is better suited for that ;). Anyways, when supporting (kind of very) old browsers is not a strict requirement I'd prefer `flex-box` positioning to floating layouts.

Comment: @lupz I am using latest firefox which should support this.

Comment: @lyraX it's not about your browser. It's about the browsers of your users.

Comment: If you dont mind to change your own elements and design then [here is jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d4v91ekb/3/) with new css and html with my own design

Comment: @KirankumarDafda Could not find the element that centers the menu, but thanks!

Comment: I have used first `30%` of `100%` screen for site name and `40%` for `.center` for set menu in center and `30%` will remain from right side. So the `.center` div will look at center because `screen occupy 30% from both sides`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear how do you want to align your menu.
But, from the sample you provided, I guess the following code would make your menu responsive.

```
.mainNav {
  width: 50%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.mainNav ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.mainNav ul li {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

See [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d4v91ekb/1/)

**Edit 1**

If you want to align the menu in a separate line than the header, Use the following code (Site logo and name is wrapped in div.title)

```
#header .row{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.mainNav {
  display: block;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.mainNav ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Please see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d4v91ekb/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Use container class to `display:block;`

```
.container {
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0 auto;
   max-width: 1200px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   display:block;

}
```

If you want to test reduce width to 50% and test it works.

[Example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d4v91ekb/4/)